firebase_core integrating issue in flutter app
I'm integrating push notifications in my Flutter app and have successfully installed the firebase_core package. However, upon importing it, I'm encountering the following error:

It appears that there might be an incompatibility with dependencies, specifically with the leak_tracker_testing package.
If there’s another reliable package for push notifications in Flutter, preferably a free one, could you suggest it? Also, if there’s a straightforward fix for this Firebase dependency issue, that would be helpful. Other parts of the app work without issues, so I’d prefer a solution that doesn’t require major changes.

This happens when there is a mismatch between the flutter SDK version and firebase_core version. try changing the firebase_core version that is supported with the package.
